# ncurses getmaxx just giving half terminal size

Tags: c++, ncurses

I have the following c++ code for a very simple ncurses application:

```
ui::MainUI::MainUI(void) : _window(initscr()),
                           xsize(getmaxx(_window)),
                           ysize(getmaxy(_window)),
                           _header(newwin(1, ysize, 0, 0)),
                           interrupted(false) {
    curs_set(0);
    start_color();
}

void ui::MainUI::showMainUI(void) {
    setTitle("title");
    refresh();
    wrefresh(_header);
}

void ui::MainUI::quit(void) {
     endwin();
}

void ui::MainUI::setTitle(std::string title) {
    init_pair(1, 7, 4);
    wbkgd(_header, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    int startpos = (ysize - (int)title.size()) / 2;
    mvwaddstr(_header, 0, startpos, title.c_str());
}
```

It does work so far except that the header is exactly half of the terminal width. I experimented with different functions, but unfortunately I can't make it work. I tried different shells as well (zsh, bash and sh) - all have the same issue, so it must be in this code.
I would appreciate any suggestions. Thx beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Should startpos be calculated from xsize rather than ysize?

```
int startpos = (xsize - (int)title.size()) / 2;
```

Comment: Jeeez - you are right. I mixed up the xsize and ysize...?